# Словообразование: расхождения в словарях

Tags: словообразование, суффиксы

В словаре Ефремовой указано, что в русском языке есть словообразовательная единица *-аист-* и приводится пример: "алгебраист". А в словаре Тихонова слово "алгебраист" разобрано как "алгебр/а/ист", то есть выделяется суффикс *-а-* и суффикс -ист. Другой пример: Ефремова выделяет единицу "-тельств-(о)-" (её примеры: вмешательство, доказательство), а Тихонов разбирает иначе: в/меш/а/тель/ств/о, доказ/а/тель/ств/о.

Такие расхождения при разборе слова в разных словарях встречаются довольно часто. Какому словарю верить в подобных спорных ситуациях, или вообще: выделение словообразовательных единиц абстрактно, однозначных правил нет, и всё это на усмотрение авторов словарей?

Answer (score 1):

Правила есть, но как вы верно заметили, они не всегда математически однозначны. Не хочу сейчас противопоставлять Тихонова Ефремовой (и наоборот) на основании только этих примеров, только о словарях.

Доверять надо (в порядке убывания приоритета):
 1. Словарю, который ближе к читающему по назначению (скажем учебный словарь против академического - в школе и в вузе соответственно)
 2. Предметно-ориентированному (синхронический подход против диахронического, например, т.е. слово в историческом понимании против современного, подвергшегося переразложению и переосмыслению; или морфемный словарь против орфографического).
 3. Более современному и авторитетному в ваших кругах
 4. Всем вместе, признавая за ними различие подходов (это для абитуриентов, если хотя бы один словарь из рекомендованных или просто авторитетных допускает такое написание, то ошибку засчитывать формально нельзя).

В отношении указанных авторов, я бы здесь выбрал Тихонова, он как бы "глубже смотрит", но это очень субъективно. Боюсь, он труден для учащихся.

Answer (score 1):

По книге Т.Ф. Ефремовой "Толковый словарь словообразовательных единиц:

1) Суффикс ИСТ - основной вариант с общим значением лица, отнесенного  к сфере занятий (журналист, танкист, марксист).

2) Важно отметит, что мотивирующая основа часто корректируется, обычно усекается: фашизм - фашист, пародия - пародист, методика -методист, фигурный -фигурист.

3) В редких случаях основа наращивается. в частности: алгебр/а - алгебр/аист. Этот вариант отмечен в словаре как единственный пример.

Answer (score 0):

Если верить Ефремовой, тогда непонятно, чем считать "а" в слове алгебра? Во-вторых, суффикс ист заимствован. Кстати, Ефремова выделяет и суффикс аизм. Напр.: иудаизм, ламаизм, митраизм. Хотя и этот суффикс(изм) заимствован. 
Может, в электронной версии ошибка. Надо поискать печатное издание словаря.

***Дополнение***

***Ответ Граммы.ру***

В разных словообразовательных словарях морфемный состав одного и того же слова может быть указан по-разному, поскольку создатели этих словарей могут исповедовать различные точки зрения на морфемное членение. 
Давайте разбираться последовательно.

Окончание из слова алгебра не может войти в новое слово, так как в словообразовании участвуют основы.

Существительные с суффиксом -ист, мотивированные нарицательными существительными, называют лицо по отношению к объекту его занятий или орудию деятельности (карикатурист, фольклорист); к политическому, научному или религиозному направлению (коммунист,  геодезист); по сфере деятельности (футболист, турист); по действию или склонности (аферист, оптимист); по принадлежности к учреждению, учебному заведению (лицеист, чекист), к группировке лиц (активист,кавалерист).

В ряде слов в мотивирующей основе происходят изменения: например чередования (механика  – механицист; шпага – шпажист). Изменения в основе не ограничиваются чередованиями звуков, существуют также образования, в которых основа удлиняется (Византия – византинист) или укорачивается (Япония – японист). В словообразовании эти явления описываются через понятия “наращение” и “усечение” основы.

При образовании слова алгебраист происходит наращение основы. Однако остается проблема трактовки сегмента, появляющегося при наращении основы (это свойственно и многим другим словообразовательным моделям). Существуют разные варианты решения этой проблемы, поэтому в словарях и других источниках возникают разные трактовки.

Во-первых, можно считать –а- (и подобные ему, то есть возникающие в результате аналогичных процессов наращения) асемантической вкладкой (не морфемой), суффиксом с неясным значением (то есть морфемой). Ученые, исповедующие такую точку зрения, будут выделять в слове алгебраист самостоятельные элементы аффиксальные элементы -а- и -ист-.

Во-вторых, можно считать суффиксы -ист- и -аист- алломорфами, то есть вариантами одной и той же морфемы. В этом случае  в слове алгебраист следует выделить суффикс -аист-.

Несколько иная история происходит с морфемным членением слов типа вмешательство, доказательство и т.п. Если считать, что они образованы прямо от основ глаголов (вмешать(ся), доказать), то логично в качестве словообразовательного суффикса выделять в них элемент -тельств-. С другой же стороны, подобные существительные встраиваются в регулярную модель типа учить -- учитель -- учительство; расточить -- расточитель --- расточительство, поэтому можно считать, что суффикс -тель- потенциально присутствует ив словах типа доказательство, хотя фактически один из элементов словообразовательной цепочки (*доказатель) в языке не представлен.

Comment: "А" в "алгебре" (второе, надеюсь), ***окончание***. Флексия. И Ефремова тут ни  чем.  "Рыб/а" - "рыб/ак" вас не настораживает? Тот же случай. Если остальное у вас выводится из подобной посылки (что "а" в алгебре не флексия, или что в этом кто-то сомневается), то это никак нельзя принять серьезно.

Comment: Я тоже считаю,что это окончание. Но суффикс ак в русском есть. Если предположить, что есть суффикс аист, то и в других словах по аналогии должен писаться суффикс аист. Кстати, вы можете привести примеры, кроме ''алгебраист'', где тоже можно было бы выделить суффикс аист?

Comment: И Ефремова так считает, смею Вас уверить. Я не очень разбираюсь в Ваших аналогиях, но хотел бы пока понять, каким образом из Ефремовой якобы следует, что "а" это непонято что. Суффикс **ак** в русском есть. Суффикс **-аист-** (допустим) тоже. Что из этого? Где противоречие, какая "аналогия"?

Comment: Я не буду искать сейчас слова, где он есть "аист", ибо это вопрос к Ефремовой. Давайте сначала определимся, чем она со свои подходом провинилась против логики "алгебраиста". Я же склонен здесь видеть нестандартное образование с "передним наращением". По типу "ламаист" или "иудаист". Бог их знает, чем это а является на самомо деле. По Ефремовой - частью "аиста"

Comment: Аналогия та, что есть заимствованный суффикс ист. А суффикс аист, тот же суффикс( по Ефремовой). Получается, что есть два одинаковых суффикса - ист и аист. Причем  не все признают этот суффикс.

Comment: *"что есть заимствованный суффикс ист. А суффикс аист, тот же суффикс"* - простите, ни я, ни Ефремова (насколько понимаю) не придерживаемся логики, что *аист* тот же суффикс, что и *ист*. Это чисто ваша интерпретация. Чтобы проводить эту линию,  надо сначала определить, что вы называете тем же самым - и почему, а во-вторых, обосновать почему разные (с позиции Ефремовой) по написанию суффиксы вы называете "тот же самый". Я Вам пример приводил. Русском языке есть суффикс **ак**. Есть отдельный суффикс **к**. (Очень может быть, что они даже общие по происхождению, но это не столь и существенно).

Comment: И ничего. Существуем как-то с двумя суффиксами. Тоже и с **ист**ом и **аист**ом.  Повторюсь, я не настаиваю на правоте Ефремовой, но Ваша её критика никуда не годится. Она на ваших домыслах построена.

Comment: (+) Вот Вам еще пример "того же самого" суффикса. **Чик** и **щик**. Извозчик  и ростовщик. Выбор формы определяется несколькими причинами, в т.ч. фонетическими. Проблем не возникает. Хотите за один считайте, хотите - за разные. Зависит от точки зрения, вернее даже -  от контекста рассуждений, темы.

Comment: аист- суффикс - 1. Словообразовательная единица, выделяющаяся в имени существительном со значением лица мужского пола, которое характеризуется отношением к сфере занятий, названной мотивирующим именем  существительным.

Comment: ист - образует существительное со значением «тот, кто связан с указанной в основе деятельностью, профессией, орудием или материалом труда»

Comment: И еще: если вы считаете это разными суффиксами, почему же тогда у Тихонова в том же слове суффикс ист?

Comment: Сверху вниз отвечаю. 1. "Чик" и "щик". - аналогия с аистом и истом. Разные по написанию, по сути - одно и то же.   2. Это Вы у Тихонова спросите.  Возможно потому, что он придерживается диахронического подхода. Не знаю.