# Существует ли единая морфемная и словообразовательная модели русского языка?

Tags: словообразование

Если пытаться разобрать по составу слово

> экспрессионизм

то можно наткнуться на два варианта:

> экспресс/и/он/и́зм/ (Тихонов)

а у Ефремовой немного другой вариант:

> **-онизм-, суффикc**
>
> Словообразовательная единица, выделяющаяся в именах существительных мужского рода, обозначающих направление или
> склонность, которые связаны с тем, что названо мотивирующим именем
> существительным (абстракциони́зм, экспансиони́зм, **экспрессиони́зм** и
> т.п.).

Возникают следующие вопросы:

1. Всегда ли словообразование идёт через один суффикс, или могут быть устойчивые пары суффиксов, например *-он-изм-*, которые можно классифицировать как устойчивую словообразовательную единицу?
2. Существует ли для русского языка единая (или официальная) словообразовательная модель или, по меньшей мере, единый список некорневых морфем?

**P.S.** Порекоммендуйте серьёзную литературу по словообразованию в современном русском языке.

Comment: Подобного рода вопрос уже задавался. Возможно вам будет интересно.[Словообразование](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/415950/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%85?s=1|0.1737)

Answer (score 3):

1) Вот определение для морфемы:

Морфема является ЭЛЕМЕНТАРНОЙ, предельной единицей языка, несущей в себе лексическое или грамматическое значение. Она занимает положение между фонемой и словом и является строительным элементом для последнего.

2) Схема словообразования: экспрессия - экспресси/онизм, экспрессия - экспресс/ивн/ый (по Ефремовой).

3) ОНИЗМ и ИВН - словообразовательные форманты, **но можно ли их разложить на элементарные морфемы?** Существует суффикс ИЗМ, но нет суффикса ОН с ПОДХОДЯЩИМ значением. Существует суффикс ИВН, но нет суффикса ВН опять же с подходящим значением (есть: залить - заливной, надуть -надувной). Поэтому эти форманты не делятся на элементарные морфемы.

4) Правильно: экспресси/онизм. А почему не выделяем суффикс И? Иноязычный элемент ЭКСПРЕСС не выступает в качестве самостоятельной производящей основы.

5) Таким образом, правильный разбор должен основываться на хороших словарях морфемных единиц (кроме словаря Ефремовой 1996 года, мне подобные словари не встречались), такой словарь и должен быть "единым списком некорневых морфем".

6) Но к словарю нужно приложить собственное умение провести  анализ конкретного слова, а именно умение составить  словообразовательную схему и понять значения элементарных суффиксов, входящих в сложные форманты.

Comment: Ваша точка зрения мне кажется обоснованной, но можно рассуждать и таким образом. Возьмём два существительных: *марксизм* (суффикс -изм) и *экспрессионизм* (суффикс -онизм). По смыслу они оба являются *измами* и в этом случае логично считать, что оба этих слова включают классифицирующую морфему *-изм-*. А суффикс *-он-* в данном случае не несёт самостоятельной смысловой нагрузки, а необходим для звучного присоединения смыслообразующей морфемы *-изм-* к основе *экспресси-*. И в этом случае имеет смысл говорить не об отдельно стоящем суффиксе *-онизм-*, а о сложном форманте *-он-изм-*.

Comment: Деление *экспресси/онизм* мне кажется нелогичным. Как тогда объяснить корень *экспресс* в слове *экспресс/ивн/ый*? Опять же, в слове *экспресс/и/я* суффикс *-и-* не играет самостоятельной смысловой роли, а служит скорее для звучной стыковки окончания с корнем.

Comment: В сложном форманте ОНИЗМ нет самостоятельной морфемы ОН, это только расширитель основы, но не морфема. В слове экспрессия формант ИJ входит в основу, а в производных словах усекается. Структура слова "экспрессия" соответствует словам  вида "дипломатия", но ИJ не выделяется из-за иноязычной природы элемента "экспресс". Вообще говоря, суффикс ИJ определяется в словаре Ефремовой как регулярный и продуктивный.

Comment: Можете дать ссылку на словарь (автор, название, год, издание)?

Comment: Т.Ф. Ефремова "Толковый словарь словообразовательных единиц", Москва, Русский язык, 1996 год.

Comment: Вера, я вас правильно понял: вам не нравится словарь Ефремовой?

Comment: А почему вы так решили, я этим словарем пользуюсь очень часто. Не могу понять, почему его не переиздают или не составляют подобные словари.

Comment: Таким образом, правильный разбор должен основываться на хороших словарях морфемных единиц (**кроме словаря Ефремовой 1996 года, мне подобные словари не встречались**).

Comment: Так здесь оборот со значением включения.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, можно в слове ***экспрессионизм*** считать ***-онизм*** суффиксом. Так эта единица названа у Ефремовой (http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136424 ).

Но у меня не получается ответить на вопрос: а какой суффикс тогда будет в слове ***экспрессионист*** (= последователь ***экспрессионизма***)?

***-онист***?  Такого суффикса у Ефремовой я не нашёл.

***-ист***? Пожалуй, да. Но тогда чем считать в этом слове   ***-он***? Ещё одним суффиксом?

У Тихонова так:

*экспрессия -> экспресси-**он/изм** -> экспрессион-**ист**.*

У него ***-он*** названо интерфиксом. НЕ СУФФИКСОМ. Интерфикс этот у Тихонова присутствует и в слове ***экспрессиОНизм*** (где ***-изм*** -- суффикс), и в  слове ***экспрессиОНист*** (суффикс ***-ист***).

В случае с  ***экспрессионизмом*** мне Тихонов пока понятнее, чем Ефремова. Может, я и ошибаюсь...

Comment: Да, полностью с вами согласен. Система суффиксов у Ефремовой не полна, если брать предложенный ею вариант членения слова на морфемы.

Comment: *У него -он названо интерфиксом* Можете дать ссылку на литературу, где он об этом пишет чёрным по белому?

Comment: Всё не так сложно. Эксрессия - экспресси/онизм - экспрессион/ист.  Производящую основу усекаем на ИЗМ и добавляем суффикс ИСТ. Сравнить: фашизм - фаш/ист (пример из Ефремовой).

Comment: _Производящую основу усекаем на ИЗМ и добавляем суффикс ИСТ._ === Так-то оно так... Только в производящей основе остаётся ОН. Чем становится ОН? Суффиксом? С каким значением? Напомню, Вы,  Vera, писали: _"ОНИЗМ и ИВН - словообразовательные форманты, но можно ли их разложить на элементарные морфемы? Существует суффикс ИЗМ, но нет суффикса ОН с ПОДХОДЯЩИМ значением"._

Comment: _ДеNiZz  –  Можете дать ссылку на литературу, где он об этом пишет чёрным по белому?_ ===  См. выше: **экспресси-он/изм**. У Тихонова в "Словообразовательном словаре русского языка" в главе "Как построен словарь" разъясняется:  _"В производном слове интерфиксальная часть форманта (слева) отделена от её собственно суффиксальной части (справа) косой чертой"._